# pickadate.js set min depending on first date input

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I using [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) to `date from` and `date to`, it was a wonderful plugin and working just nice. However, I have issue to set `min` option to `date to` field depending on first date input, if `date from` is `2016-07-21`, `date to` picker should disable date before `2016-07-21`, and so on.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../lib/themes/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../lib/themes/default.date.css">

<input type="text" id="dfrom">
<input type="text" id="dto">

<script src="../../lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="../../lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="../../lib/legacy.js"></script>

<script>
var $input = $('#dfrom').pickadate({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    max: true,
    container: '#calendar',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    closeOnClear: true,
});
var $input = $('#dto').pickadate({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    //min: [2015,3,20],
    max: true,
    container: '#calendar',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    closeOnClear: true,
});

var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
</script>
```

hope someone can give an advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'dfrom') {
        alert($(this).val())
        $('#d').pickadate('picker').set('min',$(this).val());
    }
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'dto') {
        $('#dfrom').pickadate('picker').set('max',$(this).val());
    }
});
```

this worked for me, check on this https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/690

Answer (score 0):

```
    var $input = $('#dfrom').pickadate({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    max: true,
    container: '#calendar',
    closeOnSelect: true,
    closeOnClear: true,
     onSelect: function(dateText) {
             $("input#dto").pickadate('option', 'minDate', dateText);
        }
});

you can try this
```

Comment: I've try to `alert(dateText);` see what will happen, but alert doesn't show up